# touchesBegan, how to get all touches, not just first or last?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, touch, touchesbegan

In SpriteKit's SKSpriteNodes and other visible nodes, responding to touches in those nodes is often done in some manner like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        if let touch = touches.first {...
 // do something with the touch location that's now in touch
// etc
```

This is all great, but what if I want to make sure I get the touch info of any and all touches inside this (let's imagine a...) SKSpriteNode?

= touches.first limits the conditional to responding only to the first touch inside this SKSpriteNode. How is it done for all touches in this SKSpriteNode, such that each has its location available, or whatever else it's got and carrying around.

I know. Stupid question. I'm that guy. I simply can't see how this is done.

Comment: We talked about the practice of reading the docs and understanding every line of code - this is where comes in handy. 'touches.first' return the first touch so you should ask 'What is touches?'. then when you look at the method signature, you'll see that  'touches' is a 'Set<UITouch>'. You'd also see this in Xcode with the tool-tips when you alt-click 'touch'. Now your question is 'How to access every member of a Set' so head for the Swift documentation and the 'Set' information in the collections reference. Practise asking these sorts of questions :-)

Comment: Missing: "best way to do this?", "the most efficient ?", "what's the most flexible way to do this?" and other subjective questions I don't dare ask on SO, but want answered. I know it's a `Set`, from the `Set<UITouch>`, I know how to access the contents of a Set through a `for loop...` but surely this can't be the best/right/flexible way to do something as important as handling touches... right? ! @SteveIves. And then there's the need for `multipleTouchEnabled`, which I would only have learnt through trial and error. And then there's others with the same question, the folks that follow.

Comment: But most of all, there's my annoyance that the documentation for all manner of things that should/could/would be inherent to the use of SpriteKit (if Apple cared about it and there were a lot of users), is sparing, at best...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually a view doesn't respond to multiple touches unless the `multipleTouchEnabled` property is set to `true`.

```
mySprite.multipleTouchEnabled = true
```

You'll notice that the method `touchesBegan:event:` doesn't return a single UITouch object, but a Set (a.k.a. an unordered collection) of UITouch objects.

Inside this method, instead of just getting the first touch out of the set, you could (for example) iterate over the set in order to check a condition on every touch.

```
for touch in touches {
  // do something with the touch object
  print(touch.location(mySKNodeObject))
}
```

Comment: this is the answer

Comment: Is this really the extent of it? @Fluidity nothing better, more exacting? Is there nothing more... polished and purposeful?

Comment: not without more info. there are limitless examples. @Confused if you understood how sets work then you would know how to use a set of touches. What are you trying to do with all of these touches? There is no way to get them without iteration, because they are a set.

Comment: we need more context from ya

Comment: oh wait, you wanted specific to one node. i can write a second answer showing that, @Confused, but there are plenty of examples on here. Search the documentation or on here: "subclassing sknode" and "overriding sknode touchesBegan"

Comment: @Confused SKScene _is_ an SKNode, so if you subclass an SKNode, you can give it its own touches__ functions... independent of the main one of your SKScene....each node can be its own layer with its own touches__ methods

Answer (score 2):

In addition Commscheck's answer, this is how you can check if a node is at a certain location:

```
for _touch in touches {
   let aTouch = _touch.location(in: self)
   if nodes(at: aTouch).contains(desiredNode) {
     print("desired node found")
     desireNode.doSomething()

     // You can also do, 
     // if desiredNode.contains(aTouch) {
   }
}
```

using `SKScene.nodes` and then using `.contains` since `nodes` is an array; SKScene inherits from SKEffectsNode which inherits from SKNode.. command click the SKScene at the top, or show to the class heirarchy in the navigator, and you can trace this `nodes` all the way down to its origins...

`open func nodes(at p: CGPoint) -> [SKNode]`

You can type "SKScene" and then "." to see a list of all of it's members and the proper ways to implement them.

Also, if you routinely just need to do operations on one specific node, you can subclass SKNode (make your own custom node) and then override its `touches_` methods.

There are numerous good answers here showing how to do that :)

Comment: This just became very helpful, to solve my menu buttons state of touch problems from that other question you're all salty and bent out of shape about ;)

Comment: heheh @Confused I see you finally got around to upvoting my answers :P maybe now I can afford a bounty like you. ty